# Why is there an error when running tests but locally I can use the db just fine?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

**UPDATE**: I realized that the problem was related to using the environment variables. When I didn't use them, it worked fine. The situation is exactly the same [as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849518/avoid-connecting-to-database-while-running-the-contextloads-unit-test). I don't know if it is the best solution, but for now I have disabled the test, using @Disabled annotation.

---

Hi,
I have a Spring Boot application. When I run it locally, I can use the DB just fine. I am able to create entities using my api, they are correctly created on the DB.

But when I run the tests for the app, the following error appears:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

This is the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:${MYSQL_DB_PORT}/myproject-db
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.servlet.context-path=/myproject-api/v1
```

[(I have the environment variables set on IntelliJ Run Configurations)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAv1h.png)

These are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I know there are a lot of already answered questions about this, but nothing has worked for me so far.

Comment: have you tried setting spring.jpa.dialect

Comment: @Icarus yes! My problem is the same as the one on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849518/avoid-connecting-to-database-while-running-the-contextloads-unit-test. For now I have disabled the test. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Being in your shoes I would do the following:

1. setup maven surefire to pick up system properties from profile in `~/.m2/settings.xml`, like:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${surefire.version}</version>
 <configuration>
  <systemPropertyVariables>
   <datasource.url>${db.url}</datasource.url>
   <datasource.username>${db.username}</datasource.username>
   <datasource.password>${db.password}</datasource.password>
  </systemPropertyVariables>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2. setup maven profile in `~/.m2/settings.xml` with the real values of placeholders:

```xml
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>localenv</id>
  <properties>
    <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject-db</db.url>
    <db.username>username</db.username>
    <db.password>password</db.password>
  </properties>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

3. place application.properties into `src/test/resources` with content like:

```
spring.datasource.url=${datasource.url}
spring.datasource.username=${datasource.username}
spring.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
```

after that tests should work because IntelliJ recognises such configuration

moreover, you may setup running main spring-boot class via IntelliJ without configuring environment variables but taking advantage of maven profile.

4. install [`SpringBoot Patcher`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18734-springboot-patcher) plugin
5. place `application.properties` at the same level as `src` folder with content like:

```
spring.datasource.url=${datasource.url}
spring.datasource.username=${datasource.username}
spring.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
```

6. setup `spring-boot-maven` plugin like:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <id>run-app</id>
  <goals>
   <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
  <phase>none</phase>
  <configuration>
   <mainClass>com.tld.MyCoolaMainClass</mainClass>
   <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
    <spring.datasource.url>${db.url}</spring.datasource.url>
    <spring.datasource.username>${db.username}</spring.datasource.username>
    <spring.datasource.password>${db.password}</spring.datasource.password>
   </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
```